# Get combinations of True and False in a given length

Tags: python

I want to get combinations of True/False in *n* length (the order does not matter).

So if the length is 3, the result would be:
`[[True, True, True], [True, True, False], [True, False, False], [False, False, False]]`

And if it would be 2, then the result would be:

`[[True, True], [True, False], [False, False]]`

How would I do this? I tried using `itertools.product`, but it also lists for example `[True, False]` and `[False, True]`, while it should just make one of them (so switching the order of elements in arrays wouldn't result in duplicates).

Comment: Ok, now we know your expected output, what issue are you having with the code you attempted?

Comment: This does not provide enough info to answer.  What are you doing?  Please provide some sample of your code...

Comment: please add code of what you already tried

Comment: Have you got your solution ?

Answer (score 4):

**If order does matter in the output arrays:**

You need `itertools.product`, assuming all you want is the various combinations:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.product([True,False], repeat=2))
[(True, True), (True, False), (False, True), (False, False)]
>>> list(itertools.product([True,False], repeat=3))
[(True, True, True),
 (True, True, False),
 (True, False, True),
 (True, False, False),
 (False, True, True),
 (False, True, False),
 (False, False, True), (False, False, False)]
```

Comment: This is clearly not what the OP is after.  The first sentence explains "the order does not matter", and neither of your outputs match the OP's expectations.

Comment: I like this solution because I was looking for a way where order DID matter.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a simple way of achieving this with itertools.

Here is a simple solution

```
def combinations(n):
    return [[True] * k + [False] * (n - k) for k in range(n + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get your result like this:

```
import itertools

def combination(list_,n):
    sub_result=(itertools.product(list_, repeat=n))
    return set([tuple(sorted(k)) for k in sub_result])

print(combination([True,False],3))
```

Test_case 1:

with n=2:

```
{(False, True), (False, False), (True, True)}
```

test_case 2:

with n=3:

```
{(False, True, True), (True, True, True), (False, False, False), (False, False, True)}
```